# Minecraft Windows 10 Edition Splitscreen

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In the Settings for Minecraft Windows 10 Edition under Video there are options concerning Split Screen, I've never been able to use splitscreen so I'm wondering if anyone can tell me if I'm doing something wrong or if Splitscreen just isn't there.
[image: Screenshot of Settings in Question]

Comment: whoops. read Minecraft as Microsoft. i haven't seen the option myself but is this *"option concerning Split Screen"* just settings or a button? if the latter what happens when you to press it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Console Minecraft uses split screen if you play with multiple players on one console. Since Windows 10 edition is practically the same game, it also has this option.

I think Windows 10 edition also allows to play with USB controllers. So you could for example play with one person on keyboard and mouse, three on controllers and a split screen.

I did not confirm that splitscreen actually works, it likely doesn't. There is [this bug report](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-30338) for it.

Comment: I've plugged in 2 Xbox 360 Wired Controllers and there was no option to start a splitscreen game

Comment: Have you restarted the game? If that doesn't work, then maybe I was wrong and there's no controller support. Maybe it's just a dead button that's supposed to start split screen, but it isn't actually implemented.

Comment: I've tried it multiple times, I think you're right about it being a dead button

Comment: I'll ask some experts this afternoon.

Comment: The experts say that the buttons are the same on all platforms. Splitscreen might work, but probably doesn't.

Comment: I reported it as a bug now: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-30338

Comment: @TimFisher The report has been closed as "cannot reproduce". Do you still see the same behaviour? If yes, please comment on the bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Split-screen has not been added to windows 10 minecraft.

There is an [open feedback post](https://feedback.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/community/posts/360028847492-Split-Screen-for-Windows-10?flash_digest=eced49b0a1de421adc76ea9d8aafeac711de3b8b) on the Official Feedback website where community members can vote for the feature to be added.

If you want this feature to be added, you should vote for it there.